Dynamic Addition of two arrays across cells
I have 2 dynamic 2d arrays of equal length n x y. I want to add every entry of row n of the 1st array to every entry of row n of the 2nd array for every row. It will make a n x n spilled 2d array for each row. Based on some criteria I want to filter out 1 value out of it at a later stage. I have made a formula that can do that but has no spill behavior. I want it to be dynamic and expand to n rows automatically without dragging it.

I know the reason it is not dynamic is because of the row_num entry of the index formula. I tried to use sequence formula but it messed up the addition. Any non-VBA solution to this?
Edit:
I want this output in U47
The formula used in U47 is
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX($M$47#,ROW(M47)-ROW($M$47)+1,) + TRANSPOSE(INDEX($Q$47#,ROW(M47)-ROW($M$47)+1,)))

I want this output in U48
In my case, I can't have this because I will have a spill error. I know I can't have a 4 x 4 output in one cell because it will spill if I have a value in a cell below it.
However, I will only use one value out of the 16 values depending on certain criteria. One thing I can do is to apply the criteria in the cell like this 
The problem is that the array doesn't remain dynamic. I have to drag it every time the number of rows of array M47# and Q47# changes. I want it to be dynamic. What can I do to encounter this problem?

Addition will result in a y x y 2d array not n x n 2d array

=TRANSPOSE(INDEX($M$47#,ROW(M47)-ROW($M$47)+1,) + TRANSPOSE(INDEX($Q$47#,ROW(M47)-ROW($M$47)+1,))) formula in the cell

Side note: it's better to include your formula as text and not as a screencapture, that way people who want to test it out don't need to retype it all.

Not sure whether you are trying to accomplish something like this or not:


• Formula used in cell U47
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TOROW(Q47#)+TOCOL(M47#)),4)


Edit: Updated formula:


=DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(M47:T49)),LAMBDA(α,δ,
 LET(φ,TOCOL(INDEX(M47#,δ,))+INDEX(Q47#,δ,),
 VSTACK(α,IFNA(MIN(φ),""))))),1)



No not like that. I want to add 1st row entries of Array M47# i.e. 0.8,1.2,1.8,3.2 to 1st row entries of Array Q47# i.e. 0,0,0,0 it will give out a 4x4 2d array in U47 and same for second row and so on. I have already done this. I want a formula to do this for every row and spit the output in same row i.e. for 2nd row I want my output in U48. I know that 4x4 output can't reside in 4x1 space. So suppose I want one value out of 4x4 based on a given criteria. Let criteria be min value. So formula should spit values in adjacent rows and be dynamic. My formula does not remain dynamic.

By addition I mean each entry of M47# been added to each entry of Q47#. But not at once. One row at a time. Your solution adds each entry of whole array to each entry of other array. What I want is to add 1st row entries of both arrays then 2nd row entries of both array. Hope it is more clear now.

Addition will spit out 4x4 for each row. 4x4 for U47 and 4x4 for U48. And there is no need to drag the formula. It should be dynamic in nature.

Thanks for the feedback. I have edited my post.

Yes blue ones are my output. But in last image output have no color.

I don't want my output to spill to other rows so consider the last image as output.

It's basically the same formula but wrapped inside min() function.

Yes it is my expected outcome but I want first 4 rows condensed in U47 and next 4 rows to be condensed in U48 depending on a criteria like min() function.

Moreover, I want my output to be a dynamic array.

@OsamaAnwar updated and if resolved please click on the check mark beside the answer

@OsamaAnwar you are yet to reply and share feedback the solution is posted well 2 days back if you refer

Sorry, I wasn't able to implement your solution

@OsamaAnwar why? It is working on my end. can you show how you are not able to implement the solution

I meant I wasn't able to test it.

@OsamaAnwar ok, please try and let me know

Btw use sequence(rows(M47#)) instead of M47:T49. Moreover, could you elaborate on working of lambda here. I can't get my head around it. In future, I also want to know the location of the output value within the 4x4 array. In this case it is 1st row and 1st column but it won't be always that would this formula be able to handle that. Can you suggest a solution without lambda.

Ok, @OsamaAnwar I will try to update but I am not sure whether or not it is possible without LAMBDA(). To get the location that is a different question altogether which you need to raise a fresh question by showing what you have tried on your own albeit not the one i have shown.

I have a formula to compute the location but it suffers the same fate i.e. it is not dynamic and needs to be dragged.

can you build on this =INDEX(M47#,1,):INDEX(M47#,ROWS(M47#),)

I understand the formula. Thanks for your help. You deserve a check mark. I don't think there may be a non-vba solution that don't involve lambda. Reduce seems to be the only way to loop. If you come across such solution do share please.

Just use sequence(rows(M47#)) instead of sequence(rows(M47:T49)) it is a more dynamic option. If you edit it I would appreciate it

@OsamaAnwar there is a reason I have used so both the arrays are taken into consideration, wait i am trying to create another way using MAP()
